# How to interpret a negative linear regression coefficient for a logged outcome variable?

Tags: linear-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have a linear regression model where the dependent variable is logged and an independent variable is linear. The slope coefficient for a key independent variable is negative: $-.0564$. Not sure how to interpret.

Do I use the absolute value then turn it into a negative like this:
$(\exp(0.0564)-1) \cdot 100 = 5.80$

or

Do I plug in the negative coefficient like this:
$(\exp(-0.0564)-1) \cdot 100 = -5.48$

In other words, do I use the absolute figure and then turn that into a negative or do I plug in the negative coefficient? How would I phrase my findings in terms of a one-unit increase in X is associated with a __ percent decrease in Y? As you can see, these two formulas produce 2 different answers.

Comment: Could you add more details about your model? That would help us to answer the question. Here are some comments: Normally, you would just exponentiate the regression coefficient, so just $\exp{(\beta)}$. If the coefficient is negative, $\exp{(\beta)}<1$ and if the coefficient is positive, then $\exp(\beta)>1$. I think the interpretation is like this: the exponentiated coefficient is the multiplicative term to use to calculate the estimated dependent variable when the independent variable increases by 1 unit. In this case, the multiplicative term is $0.945$. See also [here](http://goo.gl/SJPWh).

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for the clarification. I will delete my comment and wait until the OP provides additional information about his goals. How would one calculate the mean?

Comment: @COOLSerdash - I think it should stay; it's a relevant comment, it just needs some qualification.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Sorrt, somehow I missed the question about calculating the mean. If it's normal on the log scale, then conditioning on knowing the parameter values, you'd be computing the mean of a lognormal ($\exp(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)$). If you don't condition on at least the variance-parameter, the exponentiated estimate is instead log-t ... and then it doesn't have a mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Glen_b. That's very interesting. Coming from epidemiology, I've never thought about Poisson regression in that way.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Sorry, I must have missed something. My comments weren't intended to apply to Poisson regression, only to the case where you take logs and then fit a linear regression (thereby, I was thinking, assuming normality on the log-scale, at least of the coefficient-estimates). That action's not really appropriate for the Poisson case. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Glen_b Ah now your comments make perfect sense to me! I thought by "log linear model" the OP meant Poisson regression rather than a linear regression with a log-transformed outcome (I think Poisson regression is sometimes called log-linear model). But re-reading the question I think you are perfectly right in assuming that the OP meant a linear regression with log-transformed outcomes (otherwise he wouldn't mention that the outcome was log-transformed, I guess).

Comment: @COOLSerdash Yeah, I agree that normally statisticians would use log-linear model refer to a model whose linear predictor has a log-link (which is natural in the Poisson regression case), but as you note, the question says "where the dependent variable is logged", clearly suggesting modelling $\log(y) = \alpha + \beta x+\varepsilon$. Needless to say, I *don't* think it's a duplicate of a Poisson regression question, which would model $\log(\text{E}(y))$ as linear in $x$, not $\text{E}(\log(y))$.

Comment: @Glen_b I totally agree and voted for reopening.

Comment: Perhaps exponentiating both sides of the regression equation would make it easier to understand and interpret. Also, I agree with the first comment that you do *not* take absolute value but use the original one.

Answer (score 4):

You should not take the absolute value of the coefficient--although this would let you know the effect of a 1-unit decrease in X. Think of it this way:

Using the original negative coefficient, this equation shows the percentage change in Y for a 1-unit increase in X:

> (exp[−0.0564*1]−1)⋅100=−5.48

Your "absolute value" equation actually shows the percentage change in Y for a 1-unit decrease in X:

> (exp[-0.0564*-1]−1)⋅100=5.80

You can use a [percentage change calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/percentchangecalc.html) to see how both of these percentages map onto a 1-unit change in X. Imagine that a 1-unit change in X were associated with a 58-unit change in linear Y:

- Our linear version of Y going from 1,000 to 1,058 is a 5.8% increase.
- Our linear version of Y going from 1,058 to 1,000 is a 5.482% decrease.